# recyclerview chatting UI of firebasetool

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

It is normal for a chat message to be issued per item. But as you see, one page goes over. Where is the problem? There is no problem with xml code.

[my app state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/578T2.png)

`public class ChatRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {`

private ArrayList Data = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList MeData = new ArrayList();

@NonNull
   @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if(viewType == 0) {
                ...
            }
            else {
              ...
            }

```
}
```

public int getItemViewType(int position) {

```
    //return position % 2 * 2;
    return 0;
}
```

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

}

class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

}

And what should I do when I have to represent the other person and me?
I changed the return value of getItemViewType (int position) and I get an error when I scroll down.

Comment: your item xml inside onCreateViewHolder, have you set the height as match parent?

Comment: if(viewType == 0) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chatitem, parent, false);
                return new ViewHolder0(view);   //1 view type
            }
            else {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chatitem2, parent, false);
                return new ViewHolder2(view);   //2 view type
            }

Comment: of course......

Comment: paste those two layout items xml  (chatitem1 and chatitem2)code?

Comment: ah sorry xml code error is true. thank you

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: i use realtime-firebase and javacode